# .NET Tab Control Selected Index - strange behaviour

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, tabcontrol

I have a tab control with 7 pages in it.  I have a view model which enables two buttons for backwards and forwards navigation through the tab control.  This was working fine, but has started behaving strangely, so that when you are positioned on tab index 1, and want to set it to tab index 0, it immediately selects tab index 3, and displays that tab page with no controls on it. Pressing the back button from any other tab page has no problems and pressing the forward button, similar.  I tried 'hard-coding' the selected tab, and got exactly the same results.  The code is shown below:

```
public class ViewModel

    Private WithEvents tabControl As TabControl

.
.
.
    Public Sub NextTab()
        If tabControl.SelectedIndex < tabControl.TabCount Then
            tabControl.SelectedIndex += 1
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub PreviousTab()
        If tabControl.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
            ' The code in the If statement below is trying to work around the problem, none of which has been successful
            If tabControl.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
                'tabControl.SelectedIndex = 0
                tabControl.SelectedTab = tabControl.TabPages(0)
                tabControl.TabPages(0).Focus()
            Else
                tabControl.SelectedIndex -= 1
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
.
.
.
End Class

Dim vm as new ViewModel(tcInfoTabs)
.
.
.


Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    vm.NextTab()
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
    vm.PreviousTab()
End Sub
```

Trying to move the tab from Index 1 to index zero always results in it moving to index 3.  Hard coding the position in the immediate window has the same result:  tabControl.SelectedIndex = 1 -> ends up pointing a 3.  There are no other events in the rest of the form.  If you are on tab 2 and subtract 1 you end up on tab 1.  If you are on tab 1 and subtract 1 you end up on tab 3.  This was working, and stopped.  I am using .Net 4.0, any suggestions welcome.

Comment: It seems that you have a problem with the SelectedIndex and the tests. With the next button, increment if under **tabcount - 1**. With the previous button, decrement it if greater than 0.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  You either have a "corrupt" form, or you've somehow got events being handled somewhere that you're not aware of.  Try searching the project for your TabControl named "tcInfoTabs".

Comment: Why isn't your code like this: Sub NextTab() If tabControl.SelectedIndex < tabControl.TabCount-1 Then
            tabControl.SelectedIndex += 1 End If //----//
Sub PreviousTab()
        If tabControl.SelectedIndex > 0 Then    
                tabControl.SelectedIndex -= 1

Comment: Thank you for all your comments.  First, I have searched for other events associated with tcInfo - this is the only place I am handling it, that I have been able to find, and I wrote the code.  Second, the next and previous methods work fine, except for the case selectedIndex=1.  Idle_Mind - I can't figure out how my form could be corrupt - I have looked at the designer, I can see all of the tab pages being added to the tab control, nothing else seems to be there.

Comment: Finally, there is the weird behavior that if you set the selected index to 0, it jumps to tab page index 3, but does not display any of the controls on the page. That does perhaps indicate corruption - but again, clicking on the first or fourth tab pages displays everything with no problems.

Comment: Yeah...a "corrupt" form simply means that **something** is wrong with it (doesn't mean you did anything wrong specifically).  I've had "weird" behavior crop up from time to time that I just couldn't explain.  When I created a new form with the exact same code in it the problem went away.  ...thus somehow the IDE had "corrupted" my form for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: PEBKAC - Problem Exists Between Keyboard And Chair.
At the bottom of each tab page, I had a small textbox which as the user tabbed through the fields on a tab page, would automatically move the user to the next tab when it was entered.  This field was at the bottom of the tab order for each of the tab pages.  However, when the very first tab page was selected, the Enter event for this field would be fired, moving it to the next page, where the same event would fire, and the same again on the next page.  This only happened when moving backwards.  No idea why this Enter event would fire for a field at the end of the tab order and only if you changed the tab index under program control.  Actually clicking on the first tab did not fire the Enter event for this field.

Short fix - *kludge* - add a flag that was set by the buttons each time the user moved forward or backward telling this field event not to fire.